# PHP - getallheaders() not returning Accept-Encoding header

Tags: php, web-services

I see browser (Chrome) send Request header - Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch

However when I print out the headers on the server I don't see the Accept-Encoding in there.

```
var_dump(getallheaders());
```

Is this an issue with server setting? If so what is it missing?

Comment: The encoding is only relevant to the web server (not your script) so I assume your web server software (ie. Apache) strips them.

Comment: that makes the most sense, is that a setting in apache conf that strips them?

Answer (score 0):

HTTP headers should be in the `$_SERVER` array with keys prefixed with `HTTP_`.

If the `Accept-Encoding` header is not in the HTTP request then you should make sure that the browser actually sent that header.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'])) {
    echo "Accept-Encoding is set to: ", $_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'];
} else {
    echo "Accept-Encoding is not set.";
}
```

Comment: It's not in the $_SERVER either. I am certain browser is sending that header, I can see it in web dev tools.